# API page keeps not loading on Google Developer Console

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to open the API page on Google developer console but it keeps on loading and doesn't give any result. I have searched for similar problems but the solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you've added a content-filtering/ad-blocking extension to your browser (e.g. [Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disconnect/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo)), try to disable it.